# How to add pinch/zoom behavior using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, pinchzoom

I need to create a Mobile Application using jquery Mobile. I don't understand how to implement pinch-zooming  for an image that is displayed in the app.

Comment: Did you try to search stackoverflow for "jquery mobile pinch zoom"?

Comment: Provide your project so we could see what is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a particular reason to use jQuery Mobile for this? The fact your *application UI* uses it to build your UI does not mean this behavior needs to be implemented using it.

The are other options, like the below jQuery plug-in. Note that a Worklight application by default uses jQuery anyway. So you're "half-way" there.

---

I've successfully [used the Panzoom jQuery plug-in](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom/blob/master/README.md#loading-panzoom) to zoom-in an image in iOS using a pinch gesture.
The plug-in has many options so there is a learning curve, but it works well.

From the website:

> Panzoom includes support for touch gestures and even supports pinch
>   gestures for zooming. It is perfectly suited for both mobile and
>   desktop browsers. You'll be amazed at how well this performs on your
>   mobile device.
>
> iOS and Android are supported.

As a very basic test (adding options will be required to making the pinch scaling work as desired), I did this:

In common\index.html:

```
...
<head>
    ...
    <script src="js/jquery.panzoom.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="panzoom-elements">
        <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130627213136/halonocanon/es/images/2/2e/Halo_Wars_Spartan.png"/>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
</body>
```

In common\js\main.js:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    $(".panzoom-elements").panzoom({ });
}
```

Again, you'll need to play with the options to get the zooming experience you're looking for.