# Hybrid application - open image with zooming controls

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I am showing small size of an image in the page. once user click on it..it should open in new page with zooming controls.

Note:- I don't want the zoom for entire app..but needed for one screen.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my answer to the following question I mention how to use the jQuery plug-in penzoom to add zoom functionality: [How to add pinch/zoom behavior using jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798130/how-to-add-pinch-zoom-behavior-using-jquery-mobile)

My recommendation is for you to get a basically functionality of zooming your image and then utilize it the way you want to in your app.

Comment: Thanks Idan for the quick response.In my project i have only dojo.is there any plugin in dojo.

Comment: Worklight at its core is jQuery built-in. You have it there even if you Dojo for you UI. Mix and match or Google for a dojo plugin. Maybe there is already one.

Comment: if that is the case then i no need to include jquery library.

Comment: @user3896951, that's right. jQuery is built-in in Worklight. Is your question resolved? If this answer helped you, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 3):

Just open the image (not page, only image) in inAppBrowser Plugin

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

```
window.location('your_image.jpg','_blank','location=no,enableViewportScale=true');
```

Also just to be sure set the option `enableViewportScale=true` while opening inAppBrowser. That's it. Image should be opened with zoom functionality.

Comment: thanks for the quick response atanu.. if I use in App browser, I cant use my actions in it...suppose in my page there is like and share...but you can't add these button in inApp Browser rt? so is there any alternative.